# Get data from a function array using OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop, edit

Here is the code in my class file. I have separate class file and a product edit parts with  fields. When I access them in new page I get nothing.

```
function editProd($editid){
    include('config.php');

    $query= sprintf("select * From product_data where id=".$editid."");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$data=array();

     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){ 

         $data[]=$row;


        }


      return $data;
     }
```

This is how I access it in new page

```
include('prductclass.php');
$addnewprod=new  Productdata();
$addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']);
```

but I get nothing in result so how do I fill my form in edit from

Comment: Show us your full code.

Comment: how do you know you are not getting result back?

Comment: SQL injection hole. Consider using a prepared statement.

Comment: The guy is stuck with a return value from a method. I think prepared statements are a bit out of scope at this point (although it would indeed be best to learn from the start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_dump($addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']));` should get you some output (if the sql query returned results).

If you need it in a variable:
`$var = $addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']);`

Or:

```
$data = $addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']);
foreach ($data as $row ) {
    echo 'Column 1: ' . $row['some_column'name'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Column 2: ' . $row['some_other_column'name'] . '<br /><br />';
}
```

You return $data, so you will have to do something with that data.

Your current code requests the data by using the code `$addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']);` but does nothing with the data it receives.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply.its working..i have one more question  Do you think that this is proper way to pass request id in object and get data from function or its wrong one?

Comment: its done using $var = $addnewprod->editProd($_REQUEST['edit_id']);

Comment: Atleast add `if ( !is_numeric($edit_id) ) return false;` at te top of your function.  This will stop sql injection since the function won't do anything if the edit_id is invalid. (not a number). Ofcourse you can add some debugging information where the return false is, like an echo stating the id is invalid (or, `throw new InvalidArgumentException` if you want to get into exception handling..) (search "php try catch" in google)

Answer (score 0):

you should get used to a better, consistent style

```
 $myVar = 'foobar';
```

instead of

```
 $myVar ='foobar';
 $myVar= 'foobar';    
 $myVar='foobar';
```